# Change div on different select item, not changing back. [NO jquery, only js]

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-select

I’m trying to let the use pick an option and by the option they picked there should be a div showing. This is working so far but whenever the user selects another option the old div does not go away.
I’m just starting to use javascript, but I don’t know how to make this happen.
this is my code:

```js
function airplane() {
  var vliegtuig = document.getElementById('vliegtuig').value;
  if (vliegtuig == 1) {
    document.getElementById('vliegtuig_1').style.display = 'block';
  } else if (vliegtuig == 2) {
    document.getElementById('vliegtuig_2').style.display = 'block';
  } else if (vliegtuig == 3) {
    document.getElementById('vliegtuig_3').style.display = 'block';
  } else if (vliegtuig == 4) {
    document.getElementById('vliegtuig_4').style.display = 'block';
  } else if (vliegtuig == 5) {
    document.getElementById('vliegtuig_5').style.display = 'block';
  } else if (vliegtuig == 6) {
    document.getElementById('vliegtuig_6').style.display = 'block';
  } else if (vliegtuig == 7) {
    document.getElementById('vliegtuig_7').style.display = 'block';
  } else if (vliegtuig == 8) {
    document.getElementById('vliegtuig_8').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('vliegtuig_id').innerHTML = 'Geen waarde';
  }
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select class="div-toggle" data-target=".my-info-1" name="VliegtuigID" id="vliegtuig" onchange="return airplane()">
            <option value="1" data-show="1"> Airbus-A319-100(OO-SSP)</option>
            <option value="2" data-show="2"> Airbus-A330-300(OO-SSG)</option>
            <option value="3" data-show="3"> AVRO-RJ85(OO-DWE )</option>
            <option value="4" data-show="4"> AVRO-RJ85(OO-DWF)</option>
            <option value="5" data-show="5"> AVRO-RJ84(OO-DWG)</option>
            <option value="6" data-show="6"> Boeing-737-300(OO-VEK)</option>
            <option value="7" data-show="7"> Boeing-737-300(OO-VEL)</option>
            <option value="8" data-show="8"> Boeing-737-400(OO-VEM)</option>
        </select>

<div class="hide" id="vliegtuig_1">1</div>
<div class="hide" id="vliegtuig_2">2</div>
<div class="hide" id="vliegtuig_3">3</div>
<div class="hide" id="vliegtuig_4">4</div>
<div class="hide" id="vliegtuig_5">5</div>
<div class="hide" id="vliegtuig_6">6</div>
<div class="hide" id="vliegtuig_7">7</div>
<div class="hide" id="vliegtuig_8">8</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would suggest.

```js
function airplane() {
  var allElements = document.getElementsByClassName('vliegtuig');

  for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
    //put the hide class back on the elements that may have had it removed
    allElements[i].classList.add('hide');
  }

  var vliegtuig = document.getElementById('vliegtuig').value;
  
  if (vliegtuig > 0 && vliegtuig < 9) {
    //find the one element that should be shown, and remove the hide class
    document.getElementById('vliegtuig_'+ vliegtuig.toString()).classList.remove('hide');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('vliegtuig_id').innerHTML = 'Geen waarde';
  }
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select class="div-toggle" data-target=".my-info-1" name="VliegtuigID" id="vliegtuig" onchange="return airplane()">
            <option value="1" data-show="1"> Airbus-A319-100(OO-SSP)</option>
            <option value="2" data-show="2"> Airbus-A330-300(OO-SSG)</option>
            <option value="3" data-show="3"> AVRO-RJ85(OO-DWE )</option>
            <option value="4" data-show="4"> AVRO-RJ85(OO-DWF)</option>
            <option value="5" data-show="5"> AVRO-RJ84(OO-DWG)</option>
            <option value="6" data-show="6"> Boeing-737-300(OO-VEK)</option>
            <option value="7" data-show="7"> Boeing-737-300(OO-VEL)</option>
            <option value="8" data-show="8"> Boeing-737-400(OO-VEM)</option>
        </select>

<div class="hide vliegtuig" id="vliegtuig_1">1</div>
<div class="hide vliegtuig" id="vliegtuig_2">2</div>
<div class="hide vliegtuig" id="vliegtuig_3">3</div>
<div class="hide vliegtuig" id="vliegtuig_4">4</div>
<div class="hide vliegtuig" id="vliegtuig_5">5</div>
<div class="hide vliegtuig" id="vliegtuig_6">6</div>
<div class="hide vliegtuig" id="vliegtuig_7">7</div>
<div class="hide vliegtuig" id="vliegtuig_8">8</div>
```

Comment: Note: currently there is no way of hitting the else code, so innerHTML will never be set to 'Geen waarde'.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all those comparisons when you can simply concatenate your selector together. Your JavaScript can be vastly simplified like so, and this accomplishes your goal of hiding the currently visible elements when showing new ones.

```js
var vliegtuig = document.getElementById('vliegtuig');

vliegtuig.addEventListener("change", function() {
  // select and hide the currently visible element
  var showing = document.querySelectorAll(".vliegtuig.show")[0];
  if (showing) {
    showing.classList.remove("show");
  }

  // now show the selected element
  var value = vliegtuig.value;
  document.getElementById("vliegtuig_" + value).classList.add("show");
});
```

```css
.vliegtuig {
  display: none;
}

.vliegtuig.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<select id="vliegtuig">
  <option>Make a selection</option>
  <option value="1">Airbus-A319-100(OO-SSP)</option>
  <option value="2">Airbus-A330-300(OO-SSG)</option>
  <option value="3">AVRO-RJ85(OO-DWE )</option>
  <option value="4">AVRO-RJ85(OO-DWF)</option>
  <option value="5">AVRO-RJ84(OO-DWG)</option>
  <option value="6">Boeing-737-300(OO-VEK)</option>
  <option value="7">Boeing-737-300(OO-VEL)</option>
  <option value="8">Boeing-737-400(OO-VEM)</option>
</select>

<div class="vliegtuig" id="vliegtuig_1">1</div>
<div class="vliegtuig" id="vliegtuig_2">2</div>
<div class="vliegtuig" id="vliegtuig_3">3</div>
<div class="vliegtuig" id="vliegtuig_4">4</div>
<div class="vliegtuig" id="vliegtuig_5">5</div>
<div class="vliegtuig" id="vliegtuig_6">6</div>
<div class="vliegtuig" id="vliegtuig_7">7</div>
<div class="vliegtuig" id="vliegtuig_8">8</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you hide and show elements by adding and then removing the 'hide' or 'hidden' class.

```
document.getElementById('vliegtuig_8').className = ""
document.getElementById('vliegtuig_8').className = "hide"
```

so at the beginning of your function just set all elements to "hide" then unhide 1 of them.

```
<div class="onlyOne hide" id="vliegtuig_1">1</div>
<div class="onlyOne hide" id="vliegtuig_2">2</div>
<div class="onlyOne hide" id="vliegtuig_3">3</div>
<div class="onlyOne hide" id="vliegtuig_4">4</div>
<div class="onlyOne hide" id="vliegtuig_5">5</div>
<div class="onlyOne hide" id="vliegtuig_6">6</div>
<div class="onlyOne hide" id="vliegtuig_7">7</div>
<div class="onlyOne hide" id="vliegtuig_8">8</div>

<script>
  var all  = document.getElementsByClassName('onlyOne')
  for( item of all){ item.className = 'onlyOne hide'; }
</script>
```

jQuery has the .addClass() and .removeClass() which make it easier to deal with elements that have more than one class. but if you just have 1 class name this isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should know that if you show one of your div, it won't hide the others.

In order to do that, you need to hide the one that is shown. You could do something like that :

```
let elementShown;
function airplane() {
    if (elementShown)
         elementShown.style.display = "none"; // That will hide the last element shown

    var vliegtuig = document.getElementById('vliegtuig').value;
    if (vliegtuig == 1) {
        elementShown = document.getElementById('vliegtuig_1')
    }
    else if (vliegtuig == 2 ){
        elementShown = document.getElementById('vliegtuig_2'}
    }
    //and so on ....

    elementShown.style.display = 'block';
}
```

I wrote it with your own algorithm but to go further i would wrote airplane like this :

```
let currentElement; // Variable containing the element visible
function airplane () {
   if (currentElement)
         currentElement.style.display = "none"; // That will hide the last 
   var vliegtuig = document.getElementById('vliegtuig').value;
   elementShown = document.getElementById('vliegtuig_' + vliegtuig);
   elementShown.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code which I wrote based your DOM structure:

```
function airplane() {

  var vliegtuig = document.getElementById('vliegtuig').value;
  var getDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('hide');

  for(var i=0; i<getDiv.length;i++){
    getDiv[i].style.display = 'none';
  }

  document.getElementById('vliegtuig_'+vliegtuig).style.display = 'block';

}
```